# What tv show is this about a boy travelling to another world in medieval times?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

It's a kids/teen show not sure if it's the '90s or early 2000s.

It's either another world or the protagonist travelled through time to the Middle Ages and stayed with farmers.

There was this part I remember where he made his own farming shoes with a pole under them so that he could make holes in the ground as he walks in the field as his female friend spreads seeds and water them easily. And there was this wizard who sometimes give him suspicious looks and stalk him sometimes.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a Connecticut Yankee scenario...

Comment: Hello Zen-leaf. Please take a look at [our guide to asking an ID request](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561). If anything there jogs your memory, you can [edit] your question to add the details you remember. The most important details you could add, would be whether it was live action or animation, and where (which country) you saw this.

Comment: This could also be a different Mark Twain work, _[The Mysterious Stranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger)_ (his last). One of the many uncompleted versions of this work is set in 1490 and had a TV dramatization in 1982.

Answer (score 2):

"A Kid in King Arthur's Court" (1995)

This could be the 1995 movie "A Kid in King Arthur's Court" which is a kid's movie take on the Connecticut Yankee Mark Twain book. It stars Thomas Ian Nicholas, a.k.a. 'The kid from Rookie of the Year' as a little league baseball player who is teleported back to the medieval days of Arthur. Ron Moody plays Merlin and could be the wizard character who you remember following him around.

After a search I could not find the direct scene you specified, but this movie fits the time frame and plot. Wikipedia has an extended plot line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Kid_in_King_Arthur%27s_Court